# BASH check if argv is a number between 0 and 100

Tags: bash

My curent script

```
checkargv='^[0-9]+$'
if ! [[ $1 =~ $checkargv ]]
        then
        echo "[!] How many times? $0 [number]" >&2
        exit 1
fi

for (( i=1;i<=$1;i++ ))
do
        x=$[($RANDOM % 100) + 1]
        ./script.sh $x
done
```

my argv $1 accept right now any number from 0 to does't matter, how can I make the argv accept numbers only from 0 to 100

Comment: `[[ ! "$1" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || [[ "$1" -lt 1 ]] || [[ "$1" -gt 100 ]] && { echo invalid ; exit 1; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if [ "$1" -lt 1 ] || [ "$1" -gt 100 ]; then
    echo 'error (out of range)' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

This assumes that the thing in `$1` is actually an integer. You may verify this beforehand with

```
case "$1" in
    ("" | *[!0-9]*)
        echo 'error (not a positive decimal integer number)' >&2
        exit 1
esac
```

This will trigger the `exit` if `$1` contains anything other than decimal digits or is empty.

Combining these:

```
case "$1" in
    ("" | *[!0-9]*)
        echo 'error (not a positive decimal integer number)' >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    *)
        if [ "$1" -lt 1 ] || [ "$1" -gt 100 ]; then
            echo 'error (out of range)' >&2
            exit 1
        fi
esac
```

But doing one after the other may look nicer:

```
case "$1" in
    ("" | *[!0-9]*)
        echo 'error (not a positive decimal integer number)' >&2
        exit 1
esac

if [ "$1" -lt 1 ] || [ "$1" -gt 100 ]; then
    echo 'error (out of range)' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Beware that `[` arithmetic operators always consider numbers as decimal even if they start with `0`, while the shell's arithmetic expansions in POSIX shells would consider numbers starting with 0 as octal (0100 is 100 for `[`, but 64 for `$((...))`).

Comment: I forgot to specify that integer must not be 0 as well. so between 1 and 100

Comment: @JohnDoe Oh, so I will update. (done)

Answer (score 0):

Use arithmetic instead of regex:

```
if ! (( num >= 0 && num <= 100 ))
```

(This assumes num is numeric. If you also need to check to make sure $num is numeric, then use the regex as well.)